# Cannot find "cross-platform using PCL" while creating a xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I want to create a xamarin cross platform using PCL. I do not find this option while creating a project. Am I missing any installations?

Is "Xamarin.UITest Cross Platform Test Project" similar to that? But that does not open Android and IOS directories in it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The PCL option is **deprecated .**

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos):

> Portable Class Libraries (PCLs) are considered deprecated in the
>   latest versions of Visual Studio. While you can still open, edit, and
>   compile PCLs, for new projects it is recommended to use .NET Standard
>   libraries to access a larger API surface area.

If you wan't to create a Xamarin.Forms solution, you must select the Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) template. Nowadays, everything moved to `.netstandard 2.0`